# Unity Multiplayer Car : networking particles and sound

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a Unity game where the player is controlling a car and I want this game to be multiplayer. I am using the Standard Assets' Vehicule package for the car.

The structure of the default car prefab for the controls is separated between a "User Control" script that handles the user inputs, and a "Car Controller" that handles the physics ( movements, acceleration, turning, steering etc).

You can find below the sources of those two scripts, I just modified the CarUserControl.cs for networking.

Networking position is not a problem and it works fine (I simply attached NetworkTransform component to the car and NetworkTransformChild to the wheels).

The thing is that the Car Controller script also handles particle effects when the car is steering (smoke is generated and steering track appears), and sounds (acceleration, steering, skidding), and I have ABSOLUTELY NO IDEA on how to network that...

So right now I have multiplayer car movement, but only the local car generates steering/skidding tracks, smoke, and sounds.

Any idea on how to do it?

Sources:

**Modified CarUserInput.cs** : added `NetworkBehavior` instead of `MonoBehavior` and added the `isLocalPlayer` check

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Vehicles.Car
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (CarController))]
    public class CarUserControl : NetworkBehaviour
    {
        private CarController m_Car; // the car controller we want to use


        private void Awake()
        {
            // get the car controller
            m_Car = GetComponent<CarController>();
        }


        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            if (!isLocalPlayer)
                return;

            // pass the input to the car!
            float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");
#if !MOBILE_INPUT
            float handbrake = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Jump");
            m_Car.Move(h, v, v, handbrake);
#else
            m_Car.Move(h, v, v, 0f);
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

**Default CarController.cs:**

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Vehicles.Car
{
    internal enum CarDriveType
    {
        FrontWheelDrive,
        RearWheelDrive,
        FourWheelDrive
    }

    internal enum SpeedType
    {
        MPH,
        KPH
    }

    public class CarController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private CarDriveType m_CarDriveType = CarDriveType.FourWheelDrive;
        [SerializeField] private WheelCollider[] m_WheelColliders = new WheelCollider[4];
        [SerializeField] private GameObject[] m_WheelMeshes = new GameObject[4];
        [SerializeField] private WheelEffects[] m_WheelEffects = new WheelEffects[4];
        [SerializeField] private Vector3 m_CentreOfMassOffset;
        [SerializeField] private float m_MaximumSteerAngle;
        [Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_SteerHelper; // 0 is raw physics , 1 the car will grip in the direction it is facing
        [Range(0, 1)] [SerializeField] private float m_TractionControl; // 0 is no traction control, 1 is full interference
        [SerializeField] private float m_FullTorqueOverAllWheels;
        [SerializeField] private float m_ReverseTorque;
        [SerializeField] private float m_MaxHandbrakeTorque;
        [SerializeField] private float m_Downforce = 100f;
        [SerializeField] private SpeedType m_SpeedType;
        [SerializeField] private float m_Topspeed = 200;
        [SerializeField] private static int NoOfGears = 5;
        [SerializeField] private float m_RevRangeBoundary = 1f;
        [SerializeField] private float m_SlipLimit;
        [SerializeField] private float m_BrakeTorque;

        private Quaternion[] m_WheelMeshLocalRotations;
        private Vector3 m_Prevpos, m_Pos;
        private float m_SteerAngle;
        private int m_GearNum;
        private float m_GearFactor;
        private float m_OldRotation;
        private float m_CurrentTorque;
        private Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
        private const float k_ReversingThreshold = 0.01f;

        public bool Skidding { get; private set; }
        public float BrakeInput { get; private set; }
        public float CurrentSteerAngle{ get { return m_SteerAngle; }}
        public float CurrentSpeed{ get { return m_Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude*2.23693629f; }}
        public float MaxSpeed{get { return m_Topspeed; }}
        public float Revs { get; private set; }
        public float AccelInput { get; private set; }

        // Use this for initialization
        private void Start()
        {
            m_WheelMeshLocalRotations = new Quaternion[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                m_WheelMeshLocalRotations[i] = m_WheelMeshes[i].transform.localRotation;
            }
            m_WheelColliders[0].attachedRigidbody.centerOfMass = m_CentreOfMassOffset;

            m_MaxHandbrakeTorque = float.MaxValue;

            m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            m_CurrentTorque = m_FullTorqueOverAllWheels - (m_TractionControl*m_FullTorqueOverAllWheels);
        }


        private void GearChanging()
        {
            float f = Mathf.Abs(CurrentSpeed/MaxSpeed);
            float upgearlimit = (1/(float) NoOfGears)*(m_GearNum + 1);
            float downgearlimit = (1/(float) NoOfGears)*m_GearNum;

            if (m_GearNum > 0 && f < downgearlimit)
            {
                m_GearNum--;
            }

            if (f > upgearlimit && (m_GearNum < (NoOfGears - 1)))
            {
                m_GearNum++;
            }
        }


        // simple function to add a curved bias towards 1 for a value in the 0-1 range
        private static float CurveFactor(float factor)
        {
            return 1 - (1 - factor)*(1 - factor);
        }


        // unclamped version of Lerp, to allow value to exceed the from-to range
        private static float ULerp(float from, float to, float value)
        {
            return (1.0f - value)*from + value*to;
        }


        private void CalculateGearFactor()
        {
            float f = (1/(float) NoOfGears);
            // gear factor is a normalised representation of the current speed within the current gear's range of speeds.
            // We smooth towards the 'target' gear factor, so that revs don't instantly snap up or down when changing gear.
            var targetGearFactor = Mathf.InverseLerp(f*m_GearNum, f*(m_GearNum + 1), Mathf.Abs(CurrentSpeed/MaxSpeed));
            m_GearFactor = Mathf.Lerp(m_GearFactor, targetGearFactor, Time.deltaTime*5f);
        }


        private void CalculateRevs()
        {
            // calculate engine revs (for display / sound)
            // (this is done in retrospect - revs are not used in force/power calculations)
            CalculateGearFactor();
            var gearNumFactor = m_GearNum/(float) NoOfGears;
            var revsRangeMin = ULerp(0f, m_RevRangeBoundary, CurveFactor(gearNumFactor));
            var revsRangeMax = ULerp(m_RevRangeBoundary, 1f, gearNumFactor);
            Revs = ULerp(revsRangeMin, revsRangeMax, m_GearFactor);
        }


        public void Move(float steering, float accel, float footbrake, float handbrake)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Quaternion quat;
                Vector3 position;
                m_WheelColliders[i].GetWorldPose(out position, out quat);
                m_WheelMeshes[i].transform.position = position;
                m_WheelMeshes[i].transform.rotation = quat;
            }

            //clamp input values
            steering = Mathf.Clamp(steering, -1, 1);
            AccelInput = accel = Mathf.Clamp(accel, 0, 1);
            BrakeInput = footbrake = -1*Mathf.Clamp(footbrake, -1, 0);
            handbrake = Mathf.Clamp(handbrake, 0, 1);

            //Set the steer on the front wheels.
            //Assuming that wheels 0 and 1 are the front wheels.
            m_SteerAngle = steering*m_MaximumSteerAngle;
            m_WheelColliders[0].steerAngle = m_SteerAngle;
            m_WheelColliders[1].steerAngle = m_SteerAngle;

            SteerHelper();
            ApplyDrive(accel, footbrake);
            CapSpeed();

            //Set the handbrake.
            //Assuming that wheels 2 and 3 are the rear wheels.
            if (handbrake > 0f)
            {
                var hbTorque = handbrake*m_MaxHandbrakeTorque;
                m_WheelColliders[2].brakeTorque = hbTorque;
                m_WheelColliders[3].brakeTorque = hbTorque;
            }


            CalculateRevs();
            GearChanging();

            AddDownForce();
            CheckForWheelSpin();
            TractionControl();
        }


        private void CapSpeed()
        {
            float speed = m_Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;
            switch (m_SpeedType)
            {
                case SpeedType.MPH:

                    speed *= 2.23693629f;
                    if (speed > m_Topspeed)
                        m_Rigidbody.velocity = (m_Topspeed/2.23693629f) * m_Rigidbody.velocity.normalized;
                    break;

                case SpeedType.KPH:
                    speed *= 3.6f;
                    if (speed > m_Topspeed)
                        m_Rigidbody.velocity = (m_Topspeed/3.6f) * m_Rigidbody.velocity.normalized;
                    break;
            }
        }


        private void ApplyDrive(float accel, float footbrake)
        {

            float thrustTorque;
            switch (m_CarDriveType)
            {
                case CarDriveType.FourWheelDrive:
                    thrustTorque = accel * (m_CurrentTorque / 4f);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        m_WheelColliders[i].motorTorque = thrustTorque;
                    }
                    break;

                case CarDriveType.FrontWheelDrive:
                    thrustTorque = accel * (m_CurrentTorque / 2f);
                    m_WheelColliders[0].motorTorque = m_WheelColliders[1].motorTorque = thrustTorque;
                    break;

                case CarDriveType.RearWheelDrive:
                    thrustTorque = accel * (m_CurrentTorque / 2f);
                    m_WheelColliders[2].motorTorque = m_WheelColliders[3].motorTorque = thrustTorque;
                    break;

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (CurrentSpeed > 5 && Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, m_Rigidbody.velocity) < 50f)
                {
                    m_WheelColliders[i].brakeTorque = m_BrakeTorque*footbrake;
                }
                else if (footbrake > 0)
                {
                    m_WheelColliders[i].brakeTorque = 0f;
                    m_WheelColliders[i].motorTorque = -m_ReverseTorque*footbrake;
                }
            }
        }


        private void SteerHelper()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                WheelHit wheelhit;
                m_WheelColliders[i].GetGroundHit(out wheelhit);
                if (wheelhit.normal == Vector3.zero)
                    return; // wheels arent on the ground so dont realign the rigidbody velocity
            }

            // this if is needed to avoid gimbal lock problems that will make the car suddenly shift direction
            if (Mathf.Abs(m_OldRotation - transform.eulerAngles.y) < 10f)
            {
                var turnadjust = (transform.eulerAngles.y - m_OldRotation) * m_SteerHelper;
                Quaternion velRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(turnadjust, Vector3.up);
                m_Rigidbody.velocity = velRotation * m_Rigidbody.velocity;
            }
            m_OldRotation = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        }


        // this is used to add more grip in relation to speed
        private void AddDownForce()
        {
            m_WheelColliders[0].attachedRigidbody.AddForce(-transform.up*m_Downforce*
                                                         m_WheelColliders[0].attachedRigidbody.velocity.magnitude);
        }


        // checks if the wheels are spinning and is so does three things
        // 1) emits particles
        // 2) plays tiure skidding sounds
        // 3) leaves skidmarks on the ground
        // these effects are controlled through the WheelEffects class
        private void CheckForWheelSpin()
        {
            // loop through all wheels
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                WheelHit wheelHit;
                m_WheelColliders[i].GetGroundHit(out wheelHit);

                // is the tire slipping above the given threshhold
                if (Mathf.Abs(wheelHit.forwardSlip) >= m_SlipLimit || Mathf.Abs(wheelHit.sidewaysSlip) >= m_SlipLimit)
                {
                    m_WheelEffects[i].EmitTyreSmoke();

                    // avoiding all four tires screeching at the same time
                    // if they do it can lead to some strange audio artefacts
                    if (!AnySkidSoundPlaying())
                    {
                        m_WheelEffects[i].PlayAudio();
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                // if it wasnt slipping stop all the audio
                if (m_WheelEffects[i].PlayingAudio)
                {
                    m_WheelEffects[i].StopAudio();
                }
                // end the trail generation
                m_WheelEffects[i].EndSkidTrail();
            }
        }

        // crude traction control that reduces the power to wheel if the car is wheel spinning too much
        private void TractionControl()
        {
            WheelHit wheelHit;
            switch (m_CarDriveType)
            {
                case CarDriveType.FourWheelDrive:
                    // loop through all wheels
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        m_WheelColliders[i].GetGroundHit(out wheelHit);

                        AdjustTorque(wheelHit.forwardSlip);
                    }
                    break;

                case CarDriveType.RearWheelDrive:
                    m_WheelColliders[2].GetGroundHit(out wheelHit);
                    AdjustTorque(wheelHit.forwardSlip);

                    m_WheelColliders[3].GetGroundHit(out wheelHit);
                    AdjustTorque(wheelHit.forwardSlip);
                    break;

                case CarDriveType.FrontWheelDrive:
                    m_WheelColliders[0].GetGroundHit(out wheelHit);
                    AdjustTorque(wheelHit.forwardSlip);

                    m_WheelColliders[1].GetGroundHit(out wheelHit);
                    AdjustTorque(wheelHit.forwardSlip);
                    break;
            }
        }


        private void AdjustTorque(float forwardSlip)
        {
            if (forwardSlip >= m_SlipLimit && m_CurrentTorque >= 0)
            {
                m_CurrentTorque -= 10 * m_TractionControl;
            }
            else
            {
                m_CurrentTorque += 10 * m_TractionControl;
                if (m_CurrentTorque > m_FullTorqueOverAllWheels)
                {
                    m_CurrentTorque = m_FullTorqueOverAllWheels;
                }
            }
        }


        private bool AnySkidSoundPlaying()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (m_WheelEffects[i].PlayingAudio)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sync states across your server and clients.

Inside your `CarUserControl` script, add a field:

```
[SyncVar]
bool smokeOn;
```

In your `Update` loop:

```
if (!isServer)
{
  //Clients play their smoke locally depending on the synced variable
  if(smokeOn)
    particleSystem.Play();
  else
    particleSystem.Stop();
}
else 
{
  smokeOn = particleSystem.isPlaying;
}
```

You can apply the same reasoning to your sounds - sync a variable that represents what type of sound is played, and your clients will play the sounds locally depending on the synced variable.

Comment: The thing is that smoke is not activated in CarUserControl, it actually depends on complex computation done in CarController that triggers the particles from another script attached to the wheels (this is how it is designed in the standard assets's car prefab). But thank you for this answer it actually gave me a very good idea, I'll try it out !

Answer (score 1):

To generate particle effects in multiplayer game, normally I will do like this:

```
 [Command]
 public void CmdSpell(int index, float time){

    var m_Spell = SpellGroup [index];
    GameObject spell = (GameObject)Instantiate (m_Spell, SpellCastPosition.position, SpellCastPosition.rotation);
    NetworkServer.Spawn (spell);
    Destroy (spell,time);
}
```

That means you can call this method in local, but which will be executed on servers. In this way, the particle effects will be spawn on server.
And the particle effect should be added into "NetworkManager - Spawn Info - Registerd Spawnable Prefabs"

The following tutorial can be a good reference:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I already followed the networking tuto you mentionned. So you suggest that I generate smoke like they do for bullets. I have to explore more the CarController script to find where smoke is done